# Why is the Frobenius norm (energy) of a rectangular matrix $A$ equal to the trace of $A^T A$ or $AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace

Reading through a book, it is mentioned that $||{A}||^2_F=\text{Energy}(A)=\text{tr}(AA^T)=\text{tr}(A^TA)$. I understand that for square matrices the square Frobenius norm would be the the squared sum of all elements within the matrix, but I cannot intuitivley get why for rectangular matrices it would be the **trace** of the matrix multiplied by its transpose (or the other way around). For instance it would be that $\text{tr}(CD^T) = \text{tr}(DC^T) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^dc_{ij}d_{ij}$ for some matrices $D, C$. of size $n \times d$. Maybe some sort of proof would help?

**SOURCE**: Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning: A Textbook (page 20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In frobenius norm of matrix $A_{m\times n}$, we consider $A$ as an $m \times n$ vector that its entries  are written one after the other $($ because $ M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})\equiv \mathbb{R}^{m\times n})$ and then frobenius norm of $A$ is norm-$2$ of this vector.
For example if
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}       & x_{12} \\
    x_{21}       & x_{22}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
and \ v=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}   \\     x_{12} \\
    x_{21}    \\    x_{22}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
then $||A||_F=||v||_2.$
Now
$$||A||_F=||v||_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{ij})(a_{ij})}=\sqrt{tr(AA^T)}$$

Answer (score 5):

Note that:
$$
\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^d a_{jk} a_{jk} = \mathrm{tr}(A A^T), 
$$
using your definition of the trace (take $D = A, C = A$). But then since you note the trace is cyclic, we also have equality with $\mathrm{tr}(A^TA)$.