# How to relate Frobenius norm and trace of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, matrix-norms

I came across an expression relating the Frobenius Norm with Trace as follows :

$$\|UU^T\hat X\|^2_F = tr((UU^T\hat X)^T(UU^T\hat X))$$

Could someone explain briefly the equivalence ?
THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any matrix $M$, we have
$$
\|M\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(M^TM).
$$
In particular, note that the $j,j$ entry of $M^TM$ is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij}^2$, so that the sum of the diagonal entries (the trace) is indeed equal to the sum of the squares of all entries of $M$.

Comment: in my case there's $\|M\|^2_F$ = tr($M^T$$M)$ not the opposite as you did, also could you further develop your answer how to get there ?

Comment: @Sam I've fixed my answer, perhaps that clears things up. Also, note that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ holds in general, so we can equivalently write $\|M\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}(MM^T)$

Comment: @Sam See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3960395/81360)